# "ContentInfoCompat onReceiveContent()" without lambda

Tags: android, lambda

I want to use this class:

```
`public class MyReceiver implements OnReceiveContentListener {
     public static final String[] MIME_TYPES = new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"};

     @Override
     public ContentInfoCompat onReceiveContent(View view, ContentInfoCompat contentInfo) {
         Pair<ContentInfoCompat, ContentInfoCompat> split = contentInfo.partition(
                 item -> item.getUri() != null);
         ContentInfo uriContent = split.first;
         ContentInfo remaining = split.second;
         if (uriContent != null) {
             // App-specific logic to handle the URI(s) in uriContent...
         }
         // Return anything that your app didn't handle. This preserves the default platform
         // behavior for text and anything else that you aren't implementing custom handling for.
         return remaining;
     }
 }`
```

but without lambda :

`item -> item.getUri() != null`

Can it be changed?

I think it's a loop.
I am beginner in java and testing different methods for android.

Comment: *"I think it's a loop."* It is not.  It takes a single item and returns a boolean.  Although `partition` may have a loop in it.

Comment: Notably, [that method](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/view/ContentInfoCompat#partition(androidx.core.util.Predicate%3Candroid.content.ClipData.Item%3E)) takes a `Predicate<ClipData.Item>`